# How many unlucky numbers in segment $[a;b]$

Tags: algorithms, recursive-algorithms

Some numbers are called unlucky if their decimal representation contain number $5$.

For example: $123456,245,1555$ are unlucky numbers and $111,123,147$ are not unlucky numbers.

In how many unlucky number in segment $[a;b]?$, where $1\le a\le b$

For example $a=1,b=17$ , we have the result is 2. Because, there are only 5,15.

> This is my try: I call $f(a)$ is the amount of unlucky numbers in segment $[1;a]$, then we have $f(a+1)$ is the the amount of unlucky numbers in segment $[1;a+1]$, so we have: $f(a+1)=f(a)$ if $a+1$ is not unlucky number and $f(a+1)=f(a)+1$ if a+1 is unlucky number. My problem is to compute $f(a)$ with $O(log(n))$, but I can't come to finally solution!

Comment: Could you further clarify what makes a number unlucky? For example is is a number 'unlucky' if its first digit is 5?

Comment: Simplely, A unlucky number is the number which contains digit 5 in its decimal representation.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** Solve it for numbers from $1$ to $10^n$ first. You should get something like $10^n-9^n$ why?
Then solve it for numbers from $1$ to $a.$ go in the base 10 representation of the number $a$ from left to right. How can you use what you learn in the previous step?
 Use this information to solve $[a,b]$ by solving $[1,a]$ minus $[1,b]$

Comment: This is my try: I call $f(a)$ is the amount of unlucky numbers in segment $[1;a]$, then we have $f(a+1)$ is the the amount of unlucky numbers in segment $[1;a+1]$, so we have: $f(a+1)=f(a)$ if $a+1$ is not unlucky number and $f(a+1)=f(a)+1$ if $a+1$ is unlucky number. But I think I have something wrong!!!

Comment: That works perfect, but is slow because is $O(n),$ you can do $O(log(n))$ with this approach. Why do you think is wrong?

Comment: So, can you help me with $O(log(n))$.

Comment: That is what i did. Let me know where do you get stuck.

Comment: My stuck is to compute $f(a)$ when $a\le 10^{18}$. I can't think algorithm proper with this problem!

Comment: I know, the algorithm that i want you to follow solves it for that. I meant stuck in my hint.